# T(n) time complexity for nested for loops

Tags: algorithm, time, big-o, time-complexity

```
void foo (int n, int val)
{
   int b,c;                                //+1
   for (int j = 4; j < n; j++)             //n  
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)          //n 
      {
           b = b * val;                    // +1
           for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)     // n 
                c = b + c;
      }
   }
}
```

I have the code above and I'm getting various answers for T(n) when I try to solve it. From my various answers(n<sup>3</sup>-7n<sup>2</sup>+2) / 2 and ((n<sup>3</sup> -5n<sup>2</sup> +6n) / 2)+ 2n - 6, I concluded that O(n) is O(n<sup>3</sup>). I just need to find the correct T(n).

Comment: b and c are uninitialised; the complexity is not important if the result is undefined.

Comment: The program works without b and c to be initialized. Also, I tried setting them to 0, which gave me the same run time.

Answer (score 0):

It's 4am so maybe i'm talking nonsense, but what i think is:

the first for is n-3 iteration

the second for is 4+5+6+7+...+n-1 iteration => 1/2(n² - n - 12)

the third for is n iteration

(n-3)*(1/2(n² - n - 12))*n => **O(n^4)**

Comment: Cannot be more than `O(n³) `